# Two columns inside container

Tags: css, html, margin

What I want to do is have a `<div>` with a `container` class and a fixed width, holding a `<div>` with the `block` class to prevent other content encroaching on any uneven blank space, then two columns (`<div>`'s) side-by-side inside the `block`, and to be 50% of the width of the `block`.

When I create this, I get what appears to be a margin after the first block, which I do not want. I want the block to pack up tight, no margins.

I have an example [here](http://www.scottydawg.co.uk/web_dev/columns.htm) of what I have so far, and here if the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Columns</title>
<style>
    div {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
    .container {
        background: #DDD;
        width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 2% 0;
}
    .block {
        background: #555;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
}
    .col {
        width: 49%;
        display: inline-block;
        background: #333;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="block">

    <div class="col left">
        <h1>Left</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col right">
        <h1>Right</h1>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing these classes:

```
.block {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #555555;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.col {
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
    background: #333;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Works like a charm :D

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is being causes by `inline-block`, using this makes a space appear inbetween.

Try using `float:left` to get around this:

[See on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VBqNU/1/)

```
.col {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #333;
}
```

Note that I added, `box-sizing:border-box;` this means when you use `padding` it will be included in the `width`, not on top of it. Effectively enabling the use of it without an extra inner `div`.

Remember to include a clear fix afterwards also to "clear" the floats.

**CSS**

```
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="col left">
         <h1>Left</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="col right">
         <h1>Right</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That eliminates the gap between them, but I forgot to mention that I need the `block` to stretch in height along with the columns. When I try floating them, the `block` shrinks :(

Comment: you need to clear the float. The simple solution is to add `<br style="clear:both;" />` after your `.col` divs.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix for a better solution

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` is a useful tip, thanks! Should save me a lot of maths ^_^

Comment: `clearfix` solves the height problem here, thank you JoeyP :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    background: #DDD;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}
.block {
    background: #555;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.block:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  
.col {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: #333;

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).